# Insert data based on user id

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database set up like this:

[image: MySQL database]

I have a php web site with a form that submits data using this statement:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO tasks (main_task, subtask, start, end)
VALUES
('$_POST[main_task]','$_POST[subtask]','$_POST[start]','$_POST[end]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) 
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
header("Location: xxx");

mysqli_close($con);
```

How do I set it up so that it submits data based on the id_user?

I think I have to use a WHERE statement or maybe it is best to use a foreign key in this scenario not a primary key?

Many thanks.

Comment: if the user is logged in, you can add the id_user in the session and use it to validate if a webrequest is authenticated. With this, you can reuse the session value for the PK field ...

Comment: You should read up on sql injection and prepared statements.

Comment: Magically changing `mysql_` to `mysqli_` does not fix your huge security flaw that is SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

**First**: you should escape your values like that

```
  $maintask = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['main_task']);
  and so on with other variables.
```

**Second** use this query and insert user_id to its column .

```
   $sql="INSERT INTO tasks (main_task, subtask, start, `end`, user_id)
         VALUES
     ('$maintask',.....other escaped variables ... ,$userid_variable
        ";
```

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but `mysqli_real_escape_string` takes 2 arguments (I'd recommend prepared statements instead any way) and `end` is not a reserved word...

Comment: my pain :) . upadted :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to insert user id also. without user id you can not identify which task for which user.

you can use `session`.
try like this:
when an user login in your login page set user id to the session variable like this:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['user_id'] = "current_login_user_id";
```

and this page:

```
session_start();

$strMainTask = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['main_task']);
$strSubTask = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['subtask']);
$strStart = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['start']);
$strEnd = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['end']);
$intUser = mysqli_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_id']); //get current user id from session variable

$sql="INSERT INTO `tasks` (`main_task`, `subtask`, `start`, `end`,`user_id`)
VALUES
('$strMainTask','$strSubTask','$strStart','$strEnd',$intUser)";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) 
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
header("Location: xxx");

mysqli_close($con);
```

It should makes sense :)